# PHP preg_match_all regex confusion

Tags: php, regex

this is the data

```
Stream #0.0(ger): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
Stream #0.1: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 160 kb/s
```

this is the pattern

```
/Stream #([0-9\.]+).([A-Za-z0-9]+).+Audio/
```

I need the full numbers string e.g 0.0 or 0.1 plus the audio language (ger) if it has one !

My pattern does not work
Can anyone help out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"/Stream #([0-9\.]+).([A-Za-z0-9]+).+Audio/"
```

The parens in `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` are being interpreted as groups, not actual characters. You need to escape them with backslashes.

```
"/Stream #([0-9\.]+).\\([A-Za-z0-9]+\\).+Audio/"
```

But if you want this part to be optional, you need to put another set of parens around it, and attach `?` to make it optional:

```
"/Stream #([0-9\.]+).(\\([A-Za-z0-9]+\\))?.+Audio/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`/Stream #(\d+\.\d+)(\([A-Za-z0-9]+\))?.+Audio/`

It should return number i.ex.: 0.0 as \1 group and (ger) as \2 group if exists.

Comment: @Sascha: If this is the solution you were looking for, you should accept the answer by clicking the big check mark next to the question.